# Azure publish misses referenced assemblies by referenced projects

Tags: c#, deployment, reference, azure, dependencies

I'm trying to deploy my solution to Azure, but it doesn't work. It states that I'm missing dependencies. This is correct as I looked it up via the remote desktop. I miss the referenced assemblies of a referenced project of the Azure project, i.e.:

Azure project includes project A as a webrole. Project A has a reference to project B. Project B is linked to project A by Castle Windsor (weak coupling). Project B has a reference to an external project (NHibernate).

The assemblies of the external project are not being packaged and published. They are missing on the server although they are set to "Copy Local = true" on project B.

I can't imagine the only way is to add all the references of project A to project B to solve this, right? Could you provide me with a solution?

EDIT 13:51:
It appears that the assembly NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle is the only assembly that is not being packaged. This assembly is being used by the strong coupled assembly NHibernate.
The reference trail is now as follows:

Azure -> Project A --(weak coupling)-> Project B -> NHibernate

Azure -> Project A --(weak coupling)-> Project B -(weak coupling)--> NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle

Why is NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle nog being copied? I also got several other libraries which were added by the NHibernate package (such as Iesi.Collections) that are correctly packaged.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been several incident when such problem occurred and the following discussion shows how to solve this problem:

[Problem with Nhibernate.Bytecode.Castle in MSBuild (TFS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058990/problem-with-nhibernate-bytecode-castle-in-msbuild-tfs)

Comment: Thanks for the link. It has some workarounds that'll do. I just explicitly told Fluent NHibernate to use the NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle ProxyFactory in the configuration. Thanks a lot!`var databaseConfiguration = Fluently.Configure().ProxyFactoryFactory<NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory>()`